# Calculate time between two time stamps with a gap in between in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set where I need to be able to run a calculation down an entire column to calculate the time between two time stamps *only* when the status is changed from **New** to **Done**.

If the status goes from **Done** to **New** and back to **Done** again, I need to find the new duration and *add* it to the previously found duration (this happens when documents are put back into a workflow in this particular instance).

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

The rows highlighted in green need to have their times *excluded*, but calculate the time the document was in **New** status during its entire life cycle.

I need to do this for thousands of records where *the document object ID will be changing*, so I need to easily be able to differentiate what the calculation is looking at (i.e. the same **document_object_id** vs. a new **document_object_id**).

Anything is appreciated!!

Comment: So are you basically trying to find out how long - total - a given document is in the **New** stage? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Thats absoutely correct.  I have tried a couple of things including using formula 

     =IF(AND(G7="NEW",B8=B7),H8-H7,0) 

which works for excluding the time it is not in "New" but from there I cannot figure out how to then give me the sum for each document.  I also have a formula to help me know where the document ID changes which I am using 

=IF(B7=B6,0,1)

so that 1 will show when a new Document ID comes along, but still cant think of a way to combine these two logic steps to get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be difficult to use the data if you do manage to put the total file age in the column next to the timestamp as you have multiple file ids.  I would suggest keeping what you have already and create a unique list of file ids on a new sheet (copy the full list and select all of then use remove duplicates in the Data tab).  Put a `sumif` formula that reference each file id and then you'll have the age of each document.

[image: File Age]

Comment: THIS WORKS!  It is somewhat of a temporary fix because my data set is so large and has so many calcs that Excel keeps crashing on me but thank you so much!  This was a great idea.